# Delete cached images from mobile app ionic angularjs

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have an app and I want to delete the cached images downloaded by a particular user.Suppose `user1` download few images and logout out and then `user2` logged in and download few images. `User2` should not see cached images or downloaded images of `user1`.

Cached images showing all the images previously downloaded.

I want cached images to be downloaded after logged out.

```
   if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid()){
                                        localPath = cordova.file.externalCacheDirectory;
                                    }else{
                                        localPath = cordova.file.cacheDirectory;
                                    }
                                    localPath = localPath + downloadFileName.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '-') + ext;

                                    var ft = new FileTransfer();
                                    ft.download(downloadLink, localPath, function(entry) {
                                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                                        console.log("Downloading report on path - " + entry.toURL());
                                        cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(entry.toURL(), downloadFileMimeType, {
                                            error : function(e) {
                                                console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
                                            },
                                            success : function(fileEntry) {
                                                console.log('File opened successfully');
                                            }

                                        });
                                    }, function fail(error) {
                                        $ionicLoading.hide();
                                        console.log("Error while downloading report with error code - " + error.code);
                                    }, true, options);
                                }
```

Comment: Please provide us what you have tried so far. Post your code and show us specific problem in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a good question:

Actually if you are using `ng-src`, then ionic rather the browser itself will cache those images by default, based on the HTML `image src` attribute. It's a default browser feature.

There are 2 ways you can approach this problem:

**1) Don't cache the images:**
In order not to cache the images, you will have to change a number appended to the image mostly taken as a version number. To tell the browser the version it is having is an older version.

```
<img ng-src='api/image/new.png?{{getTimeStamp()}}' ng-click='editImage();'/>
```

Appending the timestamp here always tricks the browser asking it to fetch the latest image from server.

**2) Re-Version the images on logout**

Create a $rootScope variable for image version in `app.run()` method. Like:

```
app.run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.imgVersion = 0;
})
```

Now, why as `$rootScope` because you want the entire app to get updated of this change when the user logs out.

And use this variable as a aparameter in the image src as:

```
<img ng-src='api/image/new.png?{{imgVersion}}' ng-click='editImage();'/>
```

So in your case you can change the version number soon the user has logged out.

```
app.controller('LogoutCtrl', function(){
     //Your log out code here
     $rootScope.imgVersion += 1; //Incrementing the version by 1
});
```

> **Working:** 
> In the begining once the app is installed and the app tries to fetch image `new.png?0`, it is fetched from the server and
>   cached. Cached as new.png?0. Now whenever the app requires `new.png?0`, it's taken up from cache for display. When the user logs out the value of the
>   route scope variable is incremented and now on-wards it would be
>   fetching new.png?1, which is not there in the cache, so the app will
>   again fetch it afresh, also it will cache it up. So your image itself has been changed in essence.

Hope this helps... :)

**References:**
[1] https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-imagecache-in-ionic/4646/12
[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/19142498/1904479

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Code attached.